# word opens hyperlink to '.html' format file inappropriately

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word

Clicking on a hyperlink of type .HTML in a Word document opens 
a wordpad with html source code as opposed to displaying the html view on a browser.

How to get that hyperlink open a browser with the selected html file?

Comment: That is probably defined in your operating system (and is not the default setting on any Windows I've ever seen). What happens if you click on a HTML document in the explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Operating System setting you need to change. However your question is lacking important detail to help accurately answer this. What Operating System are you using?

You need to change the default program that opens up for .html files.

---

On **Windows** operating systems the steps are (will vary depending on the version of OS):

1. Open Default Programs by clicking the **Start** button and then clicking **Default Programs**.
2. Click **Associate a file type or protocol with a program**.
3. Click the **HTML** file type.
4. Click **Change program**.
5. Click the browser (**Chrome**, Firefox, IE...) that you want to use as the default for the file type you selected (HTML), or click the arrow next to Other Programs to show additional programs. (If you don't see **Other Programs**, or your program is not listed, click Browse to find the program you want to use, and then click Open. If no other programs are installed that are able to open the file type or protocol, your choices will be limited.)

---

On **Mac OS X** operating system the steps are (will vary depending on the version of OS):

Find the **file type** (.HTML) you'd like to open with a specific app, and select it. Click on the **File** menu and select **Get Info**. Expand Open with: by clicking on the triangle to the left. Select the **Open with:** menu, then choose the app (Safari, Chrome..) you'd like to use to open all documents like that one.